# Truncate zeros from string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I see questions asked on truncating the leading zeros, but nothing found to solve my issue. I have a array of strings representing days returning from an api call.

Ex:

```
arr= ["061-094", "0561-0960", "000-005", "180+"];
arr.map(function(d){

  <div>{d} days</div> // this returns 061-094 days
});
```

1) How can I remove the leading zeros so that it displays like:

```
61-94 days
561-960 days
0-5 days
```

2) How can display:

```
more than 180 days
```

for `"180+"` value?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's no other patterns in your data than 000-000 or 180+:

```js
arr = ["061-094", "0561-0960", "000-005", "180+", "90+"];

var result = arr.map(function(d){
  

  if (d.substr(-1) == "+") {
    return "<div>More than " + d.slice(0,-1) + " days</div>";
  }
    
  var parts = d.split("-");
  
  var truncatedParts = [];
  
  parts.map(function(part) {
    truncatedParts.push(parseInt(part, 10));
  });

  return "<div>" + truncatedParts.join("-") + " days</div>" ;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. yes the pattern is hopefully a 3-digit one, however the array items are dynamic, hence I would not be able check condition like this: if (d=="180+") {}. Is there a way to check for the "+" sign and then return  "<div>More than 180 days</div>" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use *map* to generate a new array by testing each value, and if it matches the nn-nn pattern, split the string into numbers, convert to number (removes leading zeros but keeps "0" as a single value), then put them back as strings.

If the string matches the nn+ pattern, process it accordingly.

E.g.

```js
var arr = ["061-094", "0561-0960", "000-005", "180+"];

var result = arr.map(function(v) {

  // deal with nn-nn
  if (/\d+-\d+/.test(v)) {
    return v.split('-').map(s => +s).join('-');
  }

  // Deal with nn+
  if (/\d+\+/.test(v)) {
    return v.replace(/(\d+).*/, 'more than $1 days');
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

If you want to wrap in HTML, then do that too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired making a String to remove all leading zeros?

```
String strPattern = "^0+";
```

This should remove all leading zeros but not trailing zeros.

Comment: How will that work on a string like "000-005"? It should become "0-5".